# Do Jehovah's Witnesses plan a return to door to door ministry since their 2020 shutdown?

Tags: jehovahs-witnesses

No JWs have knocked on a door to evangelize since early 2020 when pandemic hits.

Is this going to continue?

Will the door to door ministry resume?

Comment: I had two Jehovah Witness women knock on my door yesterday and we talked for awhile. They were surprised I knew a lot about the Jehovah Witnesses and I told them not only is my sister a JW, but I have a female friend in California who is a JW and a man I know in their congregation who is a JW. Nice talk.

Comment: @SaberTruthTiger. Thank you for being pleasant and engaging with  the visitors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [official website](https://www.jw.org/en/news/jw/#newsAlerts):

> The Governing Body is pleased to announce that the house-to-house preaching work of Jehovah’s Witnesses will resume on September 1, 2022.

Details as to whether there are any precautions or other changes to be taken have not been mentioned yet.

Comment: @argarza I had two Jehovah Witness women knock on my door yesterday and we talked for awhile. They were surprised I knew a lot about the Jehovah Witnesses and I told them not only is my sister a JW, but I have a female friend in California who is a JW and a man I know in their congregation who is a JW. Nice talk.